# calculate rolling sum in a column based on calculated values in other columns in data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am trying to calculate values in a column from calculated values from another column.

```
DT <- data.table(X = c("a","a","a", "b","b","b", "c","c","c"),
                 Y = rep(c(1,2,3),3),
                 z1 = c(10, 11,12),
                 z2 = c(1,2,3))
```

Here in DT, I want to calculate a new column Z which is sum of z1 and z2 for first row for each X. Next row calculation should be done from the previously calculated Z +  current row z2 for all rows of "a". Similarly for "b", "c".
I did try with "for" loops but was not successful.
The end result looks like this.

```
X   Y   z1  z2  Z
a   1   10  1   11
a   2   11  1   12
a   3   12  1   13
b   1   10  2   12
b   2   11  2   14
b   3   12  2   16
c   1   10  3   13
c   2   11  3   16
c   3   12  3   19
```

Comment: NB i think your data should be `z2 = rep(c(1,2,3), each =3)` to match your demo answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
DT[, Z := cumsum(z2) + z1[1], by= X]
```